# How to mask/hide parameter exposed via URL in angular-ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, angular-ui-router

I've implemented Login with FB where I'm calling FB login API url with AUTHTOKEN variable in it. Facebook API actually authenticate user and redirect to my app url with the `jwt` token which will be in place of `AUTHTOKEN`.

**Route config**

```
$sateProvider.state('loginSuccess',{
    url : 'login/:tokenId/
    // params : {}, I know this can be used to hide but this will only work if I redirect URL with $state.go()
}
```

> **appUrl = mywebappurl/login/AUTHTOKEN**

I want to hide/remove/mask token from the url but still want to match that state for the redirection. As redirection made by Facebook API, I've no control of the redirection.

Please guide.

**EDIT**

I'm redirecting to one URL i.e FB login API with few GET parameters and one of them is `appURL` as mentioned above. FB API authenticate user and after success it actually redirect to the url which I've passed in `appURL`. FB appends the `jwt` token in that URL and what I'm trying to achieve is I don't want to show that `jwt` token to user so how can I hide/mask that.

Comment: why cant you add a resolve to this state and make it instantly redirect to somewhere else?

Comment: I can't do that because fb api actually open login page and then ask user for credentials. It's not REST service.

Comment: Yes, but then it redirects back to your site with given url?

Comment: really not clear what you are asking or what the specific problem is

Comment: @charlietfl I edited. I hope I'm able to make it clear.

Comment: You have two options with the FB login dialog: Either you ask it to pass the token back to your app in the hash fragment, or you ask it to pass a `code` parameter back, that you then have to exchange for an access token via a server-side API call. With a purely client-side app, only the first option is viable (because exchanging code for token requires your app secret, and that must never be exposed in client-side code.) If you want to “hide” it, then you have to override the hash after the login dialog redirects back to your app.